# How to persist 'defaults' local state in AppSyncClient using the in-built cache

Tags: react-native, aws-appsync

`AWSAppSyncClient` does not persist `localstate`. The previously updated local state is lost. The local state is reset back to `defaults` on app restart. i.e 
The `me` state is successfully updated after login using client-side mutation.
Upon restarting the app, the `me` state is set back to the default `Offline user`.

Network `Query` and `Mutation` work as expected.

I've tried using the `apollo-persist-cache` before passing it to `withClientState` but it breaks the offline feature and introduces inconsistent data.
Using a custom `InMemoryCache` also breaks the offline feature.

```
import { defaults, resolvers } from '../graphql/localstate';

// Before login
// {
//    me: {
//        __typename: 'User',
//        id: '1',
//        name: 'Offline user',
//        email: 'help@problems.com',
//        pictureUrl: null
//    },
// }

// After login
// {
//    me: {
//        __typename: 'User',
//        id: 'aws-cognito-idenitity-id',
//        name: 'Gnu user',
//        email: 'my@example.com',
//        pictureUrl: "https://s3.amazon..."
//    },
// }

const stateLink = createLinkWithCache(cache => withClientState({
    cache,
    resolvers,
    defaults
}));

const appSyncLink = createAppSyncLink({
    url: aws_config.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint,
    region: aws_config.aws_appsync_region,
    auth: {
      type: aws_config.aws_appsync_authenticationType,
      credentials: () => Auth.currentCredentials()
    }
});

const link = ApolloLink.from([stateLink, appSyncLink]);
const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({}, { link });
client.onResetStore(stateLink.writeDefaults);

export default client;
```

```
// Inside App.js

<ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Rehydrated>
        <AppContainer/>
    </Rehydrated>
</ApolloProvider>
```

I expect the `AWSAppSync` offline feature to handle persisting the `localstate`, and restore it using the `aws-appsync-react` `Rehydrated` component.

**UPDATE**

> @usmansbk we are still researching Apollo Link State, which at this time isn't fully supported in the SDK due to how cache can be manipulated out of the standard process. We have some ideas here and some prototype code but it will still take some time to fully support. In the meantime we recommend using the SDK without Apollo Link State.